# Подключение VNC к не авторизованному пользователю Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, vnc

Если пользователь не авторизован в системе, то не могу подключиться через VNC
Но есть возможность подключиться по SSH, в таком случае, есть возможность начать сеанс пользователя, что бы переподключиться через VNC?

Comment: Что имеется в виду под фразой «пользователь не авторизован в системе»? Экранный менеджер запускает Xorg и показывает на нём форму входа?

Comment: @andreymal при подключении через vnc, просто черный экран и далее ошибка "невозможно подключиться", до тех пор, пока пользователь не введет логин/пароль и не "зайдет" в систему. В прошлый раз, пользователь удаленного пк делал это вручную и я без проблем сразу подключался. Сейчас интересует возможность, самостоятельно зайти в систему

Comment: Может необходимо принудительно запустить какую то службу, что бы хотя бы увидеть "экран входа" ввести логин/пароль и попасть в систему

Comment: Чтобы увидеть экран входа, нужно подключить VNC-сервер к запущенному Xorg, а чтобы подключиться к Xorg, нужно получить XAUTHORITY, а чтобы его получить, нужно найти, где экранный менеджер его хранит, и если найдётся, то его чтение скорее всего потребует root-доступ. В общем, всё сложно